# Connecting to AWS RDS problems

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've got a MySQL DB set up in AWS currently, and have a web api in .net that I want to talk to it with. I'm testing the api on my local machine, and any time I try and connect to the DB using MySQLConnection with a connection string, it throws this exception at me.

```
ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.0.28:3306
```

When I connect through the MySQL Workbench, however, I connect with zero issues. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong/what am I missing?

I currently am using the Server, Port, User, and Password fields in my connection string.

Comment: Is the "publicly accessible" flag enabled on the RDS instance? Did you add access to your local IP address in the security group assigned to the RDS instance?

Comment: The address 192.168.0.28 is a private IP address in AWS. If you are trying to connect to RDS from your desktop, you will need to use the public IP address or the DNS endpoint and enable public access in RDS.

Comment: The publicly accessible flag is turned on in the db, and I use the DNS endpoint given by the console as the server.

Comment: Are you sure? The failure is for a private IP address. If you are using the DNS endpoint a different address will be displayed in the error message.

Comment: "Server=soa-a4.csz3xf1nwpy5.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=3306;Database=Melvins_Shop;User Id=root;Password=foobar;" that's the current connection string

Comment: Is the security group open to outside which is attached to the RDS?